# How do I setup ReactiveCocoa so it doesn't have to rebuild each time?

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I know that because it uses extensions, it needs to be built with the project. But if I don't change any of those files, is there a way to make it not have to rebuild the library each time I build my project? I'm not using submodules.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you say in some more detail how you've added the library? It shouldn't be rebuilding the whole library every time you build.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) for dependency management, It will add all of the dependencies and hook everything up for you. The ReactiveCocoa dependency will be placed in a static Pods project, which will only be rebuilt when there is a full clean or the library files change.

This should meet your criteria for rebuilding, and you won't have any need for submodules too!